# using javascript variable in the given code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How to use JavaScript variable in current row(it changes with every onblur request)in the JavaScript code below. The code treats the current row as a c# control Id. My question is how to use this JavaScript variable to search for the control. Another thing i want to mention is that i want to access the asp.net control property in the content page form the content page via JavaScript

```
<script>
function funAmount(quantity, amount, totalamt) {
var currentrow = quantity.match(/\d+$/)[0];
var qty = document.getElementById('<%=this.Page.FindControl("txtquan"+curentrow)%>').value;
var amt = document.getElementById(suffix + amount).value;
var total = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(isNaN(amt) ? 0 : amt);
document.getElementById(suffix + totalamt).innerText = isNaN(total) ? 0 : total;
document.getElementById('ddltaxtype').options[0].selected = "true";
}
</script>
```

and the aspx code is-

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtatthe1" runat="server" onblur="funAmount('txtquan1','txtatthe1','lblamnt1')"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Either you can make this by-

```
var qty = document.getElementById('<%=txtatthe1.ClientId%>').value;
```

2.Or You can do this by adding ClientIDMode="Static" in your html like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtatthe1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onblur="funAmount('txtquan1','txtatthe1','lblamnt1')"></asp:TextBox>
```

and call in javascript as usual

```
var qty = document.getElementById('txtatthe1').value;
```